# getting 400 bad request error while installing webpack npm package

Tags: node.js, npm

Error Log info :
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\Users\wf70\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '--save-dev',
1 verbose cli   'webpack' ]
2 info using npm@5.0.1
3 info using node@v6.10.2
4 silly install loadCurrentTree
5 silly install readLocalPackageData
6 http fetch GET 400 https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack 238ms
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for webpack@latest 400 Bad Request ( The data is invalid.  ): webpack@latest
8 verbose stack Error: 400 Bad Request ( The data is invalid.  ): webpack@latest
8 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (C:\Users\wf70\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\fetch.js:36:19)
8 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Users\wf70\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
8 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\wf70\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
8 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\wf70\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
8 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\wf70\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
8 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\wf70\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
8 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\Users\wf70\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
8 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\wf70\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
8 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Users\wf70\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
8 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:666:20)
8 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:639:5)
8 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:611:5)
9 verbose cwd D:\2017\ReactJSProject
10 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
11 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\wf70\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save-dev" "webpack"
12 verbose node v6.10.2
13 verbose npm  v5.0.1
14 error code E400
15 error 400 Bad Request ( The data is invalid.  ): webpack@latest
16 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: it seems that there are some problems with your network. or you can try to use the command `npm info webpack`.

Comment: this command executed successfully, but while installing the package getting error

Comment: maybe you can try to exec these commands: `npm clean cache` and `npm install -g webpack@latest`.

Comment: thanks it's working

Answer (score 1):

Try the Below :

Option 1

1. Open Command prompt as admin
2. `npm uninstall -g webpack@latest`
3. `npm cache clean`
4. `npm config set strict-ssl false`
5. `npm install -g webpack@latest`

OR :

Option 2

1. Open Command prompt as admin
2. `npm uninstall -g webpack@latest`
3. `npm cache clean`
4. `npm config set proxy="http://proxy.example.com:8080"`
5. `npm config set https-proxy="http://proxy.example.com:8080"`
6. `npm config set strict-ssl false`
7. `npm install -g webpack@latest`

If you get the error reason: write EPROTO try,

```
npm config set proxy="http://proxy.example.com:8080"
npm config set https-proxy="http://proxy.example.com:8080"
```

Follow Option 2

If all the above fails try to install the latest stable version of node & npm.